# Doctrine 2 - Indirect one to many association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

After a lot of searching for indirect associations, I only came up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204504/adding-an-indirectly-associated-entity-as-a-member-using-doctrine-orm-annotati). What I'd like to know is the exact opposite of that question, so I'm building up on it. Given the same entities:

```
class Continent {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country", mappedBy="continent")
    */
    private $countries;
}


class Country {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Continent", inversedBy="countries")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="continent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $continent;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\City", mappedBy="country")
    */
    private $cities;
}

class City {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country", inversedBy="cities")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $country;
}
```

Is there any way to have a collection of all cities in a continent, without having to build a custom query every time, with a field in the same fashion as the countries collection, possibly via annotations or maybe dynamic mapping?

The only way I could think of is by overriding the `find...` methods in the Repository - which I'm not sure how exactly I could achieve adding the field - and then either looping over the countries and adding their cities to a new collection, or using a custom query entirely.

Comment: What do you intend on doing with this setup once it's working?

Comment: create a function in continents to get you all the cities for each country, if you want to have all cities in a continent

Comment: It's not exactly the setup that I need, but the example was intuitive enough to use - and it's actually pretty close to my real scenario, which actually involves geographic areas. The project involves a Symfony dashboard and a mobile app that accesses data via a RESTful API. We didn't have the "Continent" in plans when the app was designed. When it was added, no care was taken about compatibility, and neither the app sends a "Continent" when registering a new "City", nor the "Continent" can be null. Since every "City" has a "Country", and every "Country" is in a "Continent", that's a way to go

Comment: Since the one who developed the "Continent" entity made it unrelated to "Country", the "City" instead has two many-to-one associations, and then the "Continent" only has this one-to-many association. My idea is to keep the classes as they are, thus avoiding having to rework other code in the dashboard, and keep the entire structure compatible with the app, without having to rework neither the API to treat the data and find out which "Continent" it is if I only add the Continent-Country association, nor the app itself which would involve a lot of red tape.

Comment: Even if the solution ends up not fitting what I'd like, the question itself seems rather intriguing, and I'm sure the answer will end up being useful sooner or later, possibly not only for me.

Answer (score 1):

First a comment about your mapping. Your mapping is wrong here:

`inversedBy="countries"` not `inversedBy="country"` and probably you want a column named `continent_id` instead of `continentt_id`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Continent", inversedBy="countries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="continent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $continent;
```

And here it should be `inversedBy="cities"` not `inversedBy="city"`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Country", inversedBy="cities")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $country;
```

Consider using validation for your entity model, the validation tool that ships with doctrine ORM will help you to get these things correct.

---

You can get such a result set by inner joining the countries with a certain continent.

Inside your `CityRepository`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

//...

public function findCitiesByContinent($params){
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->innerJoin('c.country', 'cc', Join::WITH, 'cc.continent = :continent')
        ->setParameter('continent', $params['continent']);

    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

You can reuse the query and just pass a different value for continent to your `$params` array each time you want the cities for a different continent.

This code is not tested, but I think it should work. Just leave a comment if you run into issues while testing this.

---

You can also add methods like @Edwin suggested, but you have to realize that it will eagerly load all entities. This is killing for performance if you have a huge amount of rows in your tables (a lot of cities and countries). That is why a query in your repository would be better.

---

Alternatively you can do this inside your entities by using criteria and collection filtering. You can read on how to do this here in the documentation chapter **[8.8. Filtering Collections](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)**

The advantage of using a filter is also well explained in the documentation:

> If the collection has not been loaded from the database yet, the filtering API can work on the SQL level to make optimized access to large collections.

Comment: I fixed those mistakes - as I had previously commented, these aren't my actual entities, I only borrowed them for their simplicity as an example.
For now, I ended up doing as @Edwin suggested, keeping the existing getters and looping inside them to fetch everything, but I am worried about the performance. I could also try the other two options, since the project isn't fully developed yet, but I was thinking about something that would let me keep the same format as everything else. Any ideas to keep the getters but avoid eagerly loading?

Comment: You wrote *"I was thinking about something that would let me keep the same format"*, I don't really see how adding an additional query/method to your city repository is changing your entities. Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: It's not that an additional query or method would change the entities per se, but that the original changes that added the root "Continent" entity also included controller code that uses the getters, so I was looking for a way to avoid possibly breaking things while keeping performance in mind. I couldn't see how exactly I could apply Criteria and Collection Filtering in order to avoid eagerly loading or running extra queries...

Comment: To put it more simply, I'm responsible for the API that the app accesses, with possibility of modifying the entities to fit, as long as I can maintain compatibility with what other developers do related to the dashboard, and am both trying to avoid having to reach out of my scope and creating a possible performance issue.